# Adding a web server to an existing twisted application

Tags: python, twisted

I have an existing twisted application which is responsible for maintaining a pool of embedded devices using a simple UDP based protocol.  It is implemented with the DatagramProtocol and works quite well.  It builds a list of clients, maintains status, performs maintenance and does logging.  I'm looking to add a operator interface in the form of a web page.  Ideally I would like to do this in twisted as well.

Is there any examples which are applicable to this kind of application?  Ideally I'm looking for an example which serves a webpage which displays my list of objects, allows for some input.  Any reference projects doing something similar?

Comment: First you talked about a "pool of embedded devices" and then about a "list of objects". It is not really clear your needs. Did you read the official tutorial? It is a good example on how integrated different services. http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/index.html